# How do I add multiple classes to an element with JS?

Tags: javascript

I have below JS code:

```
<script>
    function CommentStyle() {
        var elementAuthor = document.getElementById("author");
        var elementEmail = document.getElementById("email");
        var elementUrl = document.getElementById("url");
        elementAuthor.classList.add("form-control ulockd-form-bps required email");
        elementEmail.classList.add("form-control ulockd-form-bps required email");
        elementUrl.classList.add("form-control ulockd-form-bps required email");
    }
    window.onload = CommentStyle;
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
</script>
ffee
<style>
    .form-control {
        border: 1px dashed #cccccc;
    }
</style>
```

Alert works but the class is not added.Also how can I short this code instead of add new line for every id because the class is same?

Comment: You shouldn't *shorten* the code, you should instead put the class list into a `const` and use that instead of repeating the string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`classList.add` takes multiple parameters, but will not accept strings with a space in it. You can pass in multiple strings, or if you have your classes stored in a variable `classes` in the form `"firstClass secondClass thirdClass"`, you can use `.split(' ')` to split by spaces and then use the spread operator `...` to pass the array's contents into `classList.add` as individual arguments.

This is even simpler for this case, since each element shares the same classes:

(*Edit: OP actually ran this code on every page, including those without the relevant elements, so a check was added to exit if they did not exist in the DOM.*)

```js
function CommentStyle() {
  let elementAuthor = document.getElementById("author"),
      elementEmail = document.getElementById("email"),
      elementUrl = document.getElementById("url");
      
  // check IDs exist
  if (!elementAuthor || !elementEmail || !elementUrl) return;
  let classes = "form-control ulockd-form-bps required email".split(' ');
  
  elementAuthor.classList.add(...classes),
  elementEmail.classList.add(...classes),
  elementUrl.classList.add(...classes);

  // for demo purposes:
  let [authorClasses, emailClasses, urlClasses] = [
    elementAuthor.className,
    elementEmail.className,
    elementUrl.className
  ];

  console.log({
    authorClasses,
    emailClasses,
    urlClasses
  });
}

window.onload = CommentStyle;
```

```html
<label for="author">Author</label><br>
<input type="text" id="author"><br><br>

<label for="email">Email</label><br>
<input type="text" id="email"><br><br>

<label for="email">Url</label><br>
<input type="text" id="url"><br>
```

Comment: I get this error on console:
(index):1451 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
    at CommentStyle ((index):1451)
    at window.onload (waypoints.min.js?ver=4.0.2:1)

Comment: @Displayname That means one or more of those element IDs cannot be found at runtime (so we're trying to access `.classList` of `undefined`). If you get that error for this code, it would have existed for the previous code. Those elements must be on the page and ready to rock in order for you to be able to modify their behavior.

Comment: Added conditional exit, building on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62314408/cannot-read-property-classlist-of-null-js/62314478#62314478

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to access each field separately by ID, just give them all the same class and loop through that class.

```
<div class="comment-field" id="author"></div>
<div class="comment-field" id="email"></div>
<div class="comment-field" id="url"></div>

function CommentStyle() {
        var comment_fields = document.querySelectorAll(".comment-field");
        comment_fields.forEach(function(el){
          el.classList.add("form-control","ulockd-form-bps","required","email");
        });
    }
```