# Cannot read property 'classList' of null | JS

Tags: javascript

```
(index):1451 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
    at CommentStyle ((index):1451)
    at window.onload (waypoints.min.js?ver=4.0.2:1)
```

---

```
<script>
    function CommentStyle() {
        var elementAuthor = document.getElementById("author");
        var elementEmail = document.getElementById("email");
        var elementUrl = document.getElementById("url");
        elementAuthor.classList.add("form-control", "ulockd-form-bps", "required", "email");
        elementEmail.classList.add("form-control", "ulockd-form-bps", "required", "email");
        elementUrl.classList.add("form-control", "ulockd-form-bps", "required", "email");
    }
    window.onload = CommentStyle;
</script>
<style>
    .form-control {
        border: 1px dashed #cccccc;
    }
</style>
```

I want to only add some class to some ID.Yes, now, I have better style but also I have a console error :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I explained in the other thread, at runtime, this code is not able to find the element IDs you are looking for.

Please move this code to the lowest point in the page body (i.e., before closing `</body>` tag) to ensure it is not executing before the elements are ready.

If you are executing this code on every page, including pages without these elements, try the following. Notice that it throws no errors despite these elements not being present.

```js
function CommentStyle() {
    var elementAuthor = document.getElementById("author");
    var elementEmail = document.getElementById("email");
    var elementUrl = document.getElementById("url");

    if (!elementAuthor || !elementEmail || !elementUrl)
        return;

    elementAuthor.classList.add("form-control", "ulockd-form-bps", "required", "email");
    elementEmail.classList.add("form-control", "ulockd-form-bps", "required", "email");
    elementUrl.classList.add("form-control", "ulockd-form-bps", "required", "email");
}

window.onload = CommentStyle;
```

Comment: How can I write conditional JS code that check if the ID s exist or not to prevent the console error.I cant check it with backend language because the script is very complex

Comment: @Displayname I updated. If `document.getElementById(id)` is falsy, that means it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks, your code works for the IDs.However, when I try to add same classes to another ID, it doesnt work for the ID. I copied its js path : document.querySelector("#comment")
There is no log in console about the comment id.What kind of thing cause this problem? The div doesnt get the classes.

Answer (score 1):

In your document, in DOM, elements with ID "author" and/or "email" and/or "url" do not exists. Therefore, `elementAuthor`, `elementEmail` or `elementUrl` are null and you can't access `classList` property of a null error, hence the error.

Check in your HTML if you have declared elements with those missing IDs.

Comment: How can I write conditional JS code that check if the ID s exist or not to prevent the console error.I cant check it with backend language because the script is very complex

Comment: You could use `setTimeout` recursively and checking inside the passed function if each `document.getElementById` is `=== undefined`. But I don't really think this is what you want, it's bad practice. You should instead understand when those DOM elements exists (Directly in HTML, or a function that generates them) in your page and locate where to write the code that modifies `classList` accordingly. For example if you declared those directly in your HTML code, you just need to call `CommentStyle` in a `script` tag after them or at bottom of the page.

Comment: @FabioCrispino I only realized what was going on here because there would be no case where the elements don't exist when they should if the function is bound to `onload`, which by definition fires when the DOM is finished loading up. So what's happening here is OP is running this logic on every page, and he needs it to work when it can and go away when it can't. Not good engineering but just figured I'd share the tie-in with `onload`.